# display hide multiple blocks

Tags: jquery

The following part of my js displays and hides the an ul class called gallery_item_details_list which works just fine.

```
        var detailsBlock = $(location.hash);
        $(".gallery_item_details_list .gallery_item_details").css("display", "none");
        detailsBlock.css("display", "block");
        var galleryItem = $("#gallery-item-" + location.hash.substr(17));
        detailsBlock.find(".prev").attr("href", (galleryItem.prevAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().length ? galleryItem.prevAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().find(".open_details").attr("href") : $(".gallery:not('.horizontal_carousel')").children(":not('.isotope-hidden')").last().find(".open_details").attr("href")));
        detailsBlock.find(".next").attr("href", (galleryItem.nextAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().length ? galleryItem.nextAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().find(".open_details").attr("href") : $(".gallery:not('.horizontal_carousel')").children(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().find(".open_details").attr("href")));
        var visible=parseInt($(".gallery_item_details_list").css("height"))==0 ? false : true;
        var galleryItemDetailsOffset;
        if(!visible)
        {
            $(".gallery_item_details_list").css("display", "block").animate({height:detailsBlock.height()}, 500, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
                $(this).css("height", "100%");
                $(location.hash + " .image_carousel").trigger("updateSizesCustom");
            });
```

My question is now, how can this code be modified to display / hide one more additional class called for example contact_block? I've tried to change the code to:

```
    $(".gallery_item_details_list .gallery_item_details .contact_block").css("display", "none");
```

and

```
    $(".gallery_item_details_list .contact_block").css("display", "block").animate({height:detailsBlock.height()}, 500, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
```

however this does not seem to work.

Some expert help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comma between each selector:

```
$(".gallery_item_details_list .gallery_item_details, .contact_block").hide();
```

Your original, working selector was:

```
".gallery_item_details_list .gallery_item_details"
```

which means select the `.gallery_item_details` elements that are descendants of `.gallery_item_details_list` elements. When you tried adding `.contact_block` to the end *without* a comma that mean find `.contact_block` elements that are descedants of `.gallery_item_details` elements that are descendants of `.gallery_item_details_list` elements.